# Scala LEFT JOIN on dataframes using two columns (case insensitive)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, join, apache-spark-sql

I have created the below method which takes two Dataframes; lhs & rhs and their respective first and second columns as input. The method should return the result of a left join between these two frames using the two columns provided for each dataframe (ignoring their case sensitivity).

The problem I am facing is that it is doing more of an inner join. It is is returning 3 times the number of the rows that is in the lhs data frame (due to duplicate values in rhs), but as it is a left join the duplication and number of rows in rhs dataframe should not matter.

```
  def leftJoinCaseInsensitive(lhs: DataFrame, rhs: DataFrame, leftTableColumn: String, rightTableColumn: String, leftTableColumn1: String, rightTableColumn1: String): DataFrame = {
    val joined: DataFrame = lhs.join(rhs, upper(lhs.col(leftTableColumn)) === upper(rhs.col(rightTableColumn)) && upper(lhs.col(leftTableColumn1)) === upper(rhs.col(rightTableColumn1)), "left");
    return joined
  }
```

Comment: I would suggest you to create dummy data sets which has 10 - 20 rows and test your code. Preferably put your sample/dummy data here on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are duplicate values in `rhs`, then it is normal for `lhs` to get replicated. If a joining values in joining columns from `lhs row` matches with multiple `rhs rows` then joined `dataframe` should have multiple `rows` from `lhs` matching the `rows` from `rhs`.

for example

```
lhs dataframe
+--------+--------+--------+
|col1left|col2left|col3left|
+--------+--------+--------+
|a       |1       |leftside|
+--------+--------+--------+
```

And

```
rhs dataframe
+---------+---------+---------+
|col1right|col2right|col3right|
+---------+---------+---------+
|a        |1        |rightside|
|a        |1        |rightside|
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Then it is normal to have `left` `join` as

```
left joined lhs with rhs
+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|col1left|col2left|col3left|col1right|col2right|col3right|
+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|a       |1       |leftside|a        |1        |rightside|
|a       |1       |leftside|a        |1        |rightside|
+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

You can have more information [here](http://kirillpavlov.com/blog/2016/04/23/beyond-traditional-join-with-apache-spark/)

Answer (score 3):

> but as it is a left join the duplication and number of rows in rhs
>   dataframe should not matter

Not true.  Your `leftJoinCaseInsensitive` method looks good to me.  A left join would still produce more rows than the left table's if the right table has duplicated key column(s), as shown below:

```
val dfR = Seq(
  (1, "a", "x"),
  (1, "a", "y"),
  (2, "b", "z")
).toDF("k1", "k2", "val")

val dfL = Seq(
  (1, "a", "u"),
  (2, "b", "v"),
  (3, "c", "w")
).toDF("k1", "k2", "val")

leftJoinCaseInsensitive(dfL, dfR, "k1", "k1", "k2", "k2")

res1.show
+---+---+---+----+----+----+
| k1| k2|val|  k1|  k2| val|
+---+---+---+----+----+----+
|  1|  a|  u|   1|   a|   y|
|  1|  a|  u|   1|   a|   x|
|  2|  b|  v|   2|   b|   z|
|  3|  c|  w|null|null|null|
+---+---+---+----+----+----+
```